# Ubuntu 3D fails with Nvidia

Tags: unity, nvidia, 3d

I'm using ubuntu 11.10. I was using 3D in 11.04 when I upgraded yesterday, but now it's not working right; windows doesn't refresh unless I manually move them. I tried reinstalling the drivers for my Nvidia 9800GTX, and even reinstalling ubuntu 11.10, but I need to log in with unity 2D to get unity working nicely.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with shadows and speed when I upgraded from 11.04
Runs much better after a clean install. I absolutely recommend you try this instead of an upgrade.

Comment: I tried a clean install (keeping /home and /usr/local) and it doesn't work. Should I format those too?